# python путаница

Tags: python, tkinter

Надо взять текст из `Entry(Tkinter, Python)`. Код:

```
file = open(enter.get(1.0, END), mode = "w", encoding='UTF-8')
```

Выводит ошибку:

> TypeError: get() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given

Нашел в интернете решение, мол скобки в `.get()` должны быть пусты, в таком случае выдает ошибку:

> get() missing 1 required positional argument: 'index1'

Comment: Вы вообще читаете текст ошибки? Метод get() принимает 1 аргумент. Не 2, не 3 и не 0.

Comment: Я читал, в не зависимости от количества аргументов - будут те же самые ошибки

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Метод `.get()` однострочного текстового поля (класс `Entry`) не принимает аргументов (кроме `self`, передающегося неявно). Поэтому правильный код такой:

```
file = open(enter.get(), mode = "w", encoding='UTF-8')
```

Дополнительные параметры нужны при вызове метода `get` у многострочного текстового поля (класс `Text`).

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!

Answer (score 0):

Как-то так

```
from tkinter import *
root=Tk()
entry_text=StringVar(root)
def print_entry_text():
    print(entry_text.get())
e1 = Entry(root,textvariable=entry_text,width=100).pack()
button = Button(root,text='Вывести',height = 1, width =
10,command=print_entry_text).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Это ответ на какой вопрос?